# Delete files in mailroot/Badmail folder

Tags: email, batch-file, exchange-server

We are trying to delete files in mailroot/Badmail folder. I have a script that we have scheduled to run overnight, but it doesn't delete any files.  We originally were trying to delete everything older than 60 days but noticed it wasn't deleting therefore I tried to put in the MinAge and MaxAge dates to see if I can get a small portion to delete, it deleted nothing.
We have over a million files in this folder.
We aren't getting any errors when running this script. We have used this script to clean up other directories of files like old pdfs etc.

I have researched and found some mention on some websites from around 2004 that it is recommended that the folder be renamed and then deleting the whole folder, but we only want the old files to be deleted. I also can't find recent suggestions or examples of a script.

I'm hoping that someone may have a suggestion.
I want to thank everyone in advance.

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "source=E:\mailroot\Badmail"
Set "xclude="
For /F Tokens^=* %%G In ('%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe "%source%" "%source%"^
 /IS /L /MinAge:60 /NC /NDL /NJH /NJS /NS /S /XD %xclude% ^| ^
 %__AppDir__%\findstr.exe /VRI "%source:\=[\\]%[\\][^\\]*$"'
) Do Del /A /F "%%G"
```

Comment: We would probably need to see the configuration settings for your Scheduled Task. However, just FYI, and as you've not told us otherwise, if the 'source' drive `E:` is a mapped network location, your task would need to be run by a user for whom that drive would be mapped, _(which would probably rule out using the highest privileges option)_, and could not be run when 'not logged in', _as drives are only mapped at login_. You could also replace both instances of `%__AppDir__%` with ```%SystemRoot%\System32\```.

Comment: Also if you're not excluding directories, you could `Rem`ark `Set "xclude=nofolders"`, or replace it with `Set "xclude="`.

Comment: Yes, the source drive is E is a mapped network location.  Also, Sorry, I meant to remove 'nofolders' out of there, my mistake.  Very interesting what you are stating.  Forgive me but I'm not that well versed in the Scheduled Task, so I have to look into it .  Thank you for responding soooo quickly.

Comment: The Task Scheduler settings:  General:: Run whether user is logged on or not and Run with highest privileges.  Is that what you were asking about?

Comment: Yes!, because as I indicated in my previous comment, a network location will not be mapped when nobody is logged on, and if it is being run with the highest privileges, it is being run as the special user, `SYSTEM`, for whom the location will very unlikely have been mapped either.

Comment: ah!  Ok thank you... I'm going to run with the information you gave me.  I'll try some things and report back.  Thank you soooo much!